# Using scanf with NSStrings

Tags: objective-c, string, scanf

I want the user to input a string and then assign the input to an NSString. Right now my code looks like this:

```
NSString *word; 

scanf("%s", &word);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`scanf` does not work with any object types. If you have a C string and want to create an NSString from it, use `-[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:]`.

Comment: How do you create a c string? Can you edit my code to show me how.

Comment: A C string is an array of characters so you'd simply write `char word[100]`.

Answer (score 8):

The [scanf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/scanf/) function reads into a C string (actually an array of char), like this:

```
char word[40];

int nChars = scanf("%39s", word);   // read up to 39 chars (leave room for NUL)
```

You can convert a char array into NSString like this:

```
NSString* word2 = [NSString stringWithBytes:word 
                                     length:nChars
                                   encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

*However* scanf only works with console (command line) programs.  If you're trying to get input on a Mac or iOS device then scanf is not what you want to use to get user input.

Comment: I am new to Objective C and the Mac/iOS development.
I writing a basic console application and wanted to use scanf with NSString and arrived at this post.
I used the above method "stringWithBytes" but I got warnings that the object may not support the message. Though it was just a compile time warning, I searched more an found this "**stringWithUTF8String**".
u can use it as a message as static methods of NSString or u can use it as "**initWithUTF8String**" along with alloc and get the NSString object from the character array.

Comment: Does `scanf` work with `char*`? I don't want to limit the input using a fixed char array.

Comment: @SAFX: yes, but there are risks to using scanf, see [details here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2430303/154803).  That's why I used a fixed size buffer and limited the length in scanf.

Comment: @progrmr Perhaps this is outmoded? I'm getting 'No know class method' for the stringWithBytes call.

Comment: @sunny use [NSString stringWithCString:word encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding] instead

Answer (score 7):

scanf does not work with NSString as scanf doesn’t work on objects. It works only on primitive datatypes such as:

1. int
2. float
3. BOOL
4. char

**What to do?**

Technically a string is made up of a sequence of individual characters. So to accept string input, you can read in the sequence of characters and convert it to a string.

use:

```
[NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:1];
```

Here is a working example:

```
NSLog(@"What is the first name?");
char cstring[40];
scanf("%s", cstring);

firstName = [NSString stringWithCString:cstring encoding:1];
```

Here’s an explanation of the above code, comment by comment:

1. You declare a variable called cstring to hold 40 characters.
2. You then tell scanf to expect a list of characters by using the %s format specifier.
3. Finally, you create an NSString object from the list of characters that were read in.

Run your project; if you enter a word and hit Enter, the program should print out the same word you typed. Just make sure the word is less than 40 characters; if you enter more, you might cause the program to crash — you are welcome to test that out yourself! :]

Taken from: RW.

Comment: It's probably better to understand if you use `NSUTF8StringEncoding` as encoding option, not the `1`.

Comment: How to handle new line and white spaces?

Answer (score 4):

This is how I'd do it:

```
char word [40];
scanf("%s",word);

NSString * userInput = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString: word encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Comment: NOTE: You don't need to put '&' Since word isn't a pointer, and is the actual character array.

Answer (score 1):

yes, but sscanf does, and may be a good solution for complex NSString parsing.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will work for you because it accepts string with spaces as well.

```
 NSLog(@"Enter The Name Of State");
 char name[20];
 gets(name);
 NSLog(@"%s",name);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple Solution is

```
char word[40];
scanf("%39s", word);
NSString* word2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:word];
```

Answer (score 0):

The NSFileHandle class is an object-oriented wrapper for a file descriptor. For files, you can read, write, and seek within the file.

```
NSFileHandle *inputFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSData *inputData = [inputFile availableData];
NSString *word = [[NSString alloc]initWithData:inputData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```