# How to use scanf for accepting values in NSString?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have to use `scanf()` for accepting name of user in `NSString` object.
If i use `%s` then it will show me error. My Code is :

```
NSString *name;
scanf("%s",&name); //It is showing error
scanf("%@",&name); //It also show me error
```

What I should do?

Comment: Who says to use scanf???

Comment: You declare `name` as a pointer, then use a pointer to that pointer as argument. That won't work even with old C-strings.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using scanf with NSStrings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220823/using-scanf-with-nsstrings)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `scanf()`, since it can't take a `NSString` object as an argument. You can first scan characters in a `char *` c-'string' and after that create a `NSString` from it with
`- (id)initWithCString:(const char *)nullTerminatedCString encoding:(NSStringEncoding)encoding`.