# Objective-C how to read data from standard input and ignore extra (unneeded) characters

Tags: objective-c

I am currently using the following code to read the first character from the standard input (after a prompt):

```
NSFileHandle *stdIn = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
    NSString* input = [[NSString alloc]
        initWithData:[stdIn readDataOfLength:1]
        encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, after the program completes, all the extra characters get interpreted by the command line (bash, in this case). For example, the prompt is

```
File already exists, do you want to overwrite it? [y/N]
```

and if I input `noooooo`, bash says `-bash: oooooo: command not found` after the program finishes. How do I avoid this? Using `[stdIn readDataToEndOfFile]` does not work, expectedly.

I could use `[stdIn readToEndOfFileInBackgroundAndNotify]`, but if I need to get user input from such a prompt again, it wouldn't be possible.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Any particular reason you're not using scanf?

See [Using scanf with NSStrings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220823/using-scanf-with-nsstrings) on a brief guide on how to do so, and how to integrate the C aspect of scanf with Obj-C.

Comment: Thanks for the link. After some more searching I guess that is the only sane way to do it.

Comment: It has been tried and tested for years. Yeah it exposes some C which might not be to everyone's taste, but it's probably the easiest and most efficient way to do it!

Answer (score 14):

If you want to keep it strictly in Objective C, you can always do:

```
NSFileHandle *kbd = [NSFileHandle fileHandleWithStandardInput];
NSData *inputData = [kbd availableData];
NSString *option = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:inputData 
                 encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] substringToIndex:1];
NSLog(@"%@",option);
```

Comment: Can you please explain the 'substringToIndex:1' ?? what's it use? do you take only the first character in 'option', and throw away  the rest? why?