# Weird error with NSString: No known class method for selector 'stringWithBytes:length:encoding:'

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nsstringencoding

I am attempting to use scanf to assign a value to an NSString, as per the answers to **[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220823/using-scanf-with-nsstrings)** by Omar.  This is the code, taken straight from progrmr's answer:

```
char word[40];

        int nChars = scanf("%39s", word);   // read up to 39 chars (leave room for NUL)
        NSString* word2 = [NSString stringWithBytes:word
                                             length:nChars
                                           encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

However, I'm getting an error on the last line that makes absolutely no sense to me:

```
No known class method for selector 'stringWithBytes:length:encoding:'
```

What in the world could be causing this error?

And yes, I do have `#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>` at the top of the file.

Comment: Did you look at the reference docs for `NSString`? Is such a method listed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`NSString` does not have a `stringWithBytes:length:encoding:` class method, but you can use

```
NSString* word2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:word
                                         length:nChars
                                       encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

Note however, that `scanf()` returns the number of scanned *items* and
not the number of scanned *characters*. So `nChars` will contain `1` and not the string length, so you should set `nChars = strlen(word)` instead.

A simpler alternative is (as also mentioned in one answer to the linked question)

```
NSString* word2 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:word];
```

Answer (score 2):

NSString does not respond to the selector `stringWithBytes:length:encoding:`. You probably wanted `initWithBytes:length:encoding:`.

Comment: The funny thing is that *you* recommended `+[NSString stringWithBytes:length:encoding:]` in the answer to the linked question :-)

Comment: @MartinR: Yikes, Past Me strikes again! Also weird is that prgrmr made the same mistake. I'm afraid my brain leakage is catching. Thanks for pointing that that, though.

Comment: I'm getting the same error with initWithBytes.  [EDIT] Nevermind, it works when I change NSString to [NSString alloc].

Comment: I just could not resist when noticing it, and I do hope that you did not take offence at my comment.

Comment: @MartinR: No offense at all. It was a great catch. I laughed and corrected it.

Answer (score 0):

Story in short: you might want to consider a const char C-string suitable initializer for your NSString object. Also, **alloc**ate memory before sending any initializer message to the NSString object. I would expect something like:

```
char word[40];
int nChars = scanf("%39s", word);

NSString *word2 = [[NSString alloc] initWithCString:word encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Note that *initWithCString* per design only supports properly null '\0' terminated 8-bit character arrays. For unterminated bytes arrays you have *initWithBytes:length:encoding:* instead.

For Unicode characters you could consider *initWithCharactersNoCopy:length:freeWhenDone:*.