# Print Statement in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I've just started on xcode today, so please excuse the total noob question here.

My code is:

```
NSString *name = @"";
int age = 0;

NSLog(@"What is your name?");
scanf("%s", &name);
NSLog(@"How old are you?");
scanf("%d", &age);


NSLog(@"Your name is %@ and you are %d", name, age);
```

And the output I get is:

**Your name is 2001-01-01 00:00:00 +0000 and you are 29**

As you can see, the string is not printing as expected.  Please help???

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If scanf did work for NSString (which it does not) you'd use `%@`, not `%s`.

Answer (score 2):

Scanf doesn't work with objects. Here's [a SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220823/using-scanf-with-nsstrings) that shows how to read data and put it into a string.

Answer (score 1):

scanf does not work with any object types. If you have a C string and want to create an NSString from it, use -[NSString initWithBytes:length:encoding:].

Answer (score 0):

Use

`[NSString stringWithUTF8String:(const char *)];`