# strange number change in objective-c code

Tags: c, libc

I have this code to break up numbers entered at the console and return them and I do the same for negative numbers, but here is the strange behaviour I enter `0123`and the number gets converted to `83`. I am new to objective-c and c, so I need some explanation why this happened.
I also noticed from debuting this code that the change actually takes place in the `scarf function`not even in the main code block.
Here is my code:

```
//
//  main.m
//  ex-5.9
//
//  Created by george on 05/07/2016.
//  Copyright © 2016 george. All rights reserved.
//  Program to reverse the digits of a number

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        // insert code here...
        int number, right_digit;


        NSLog(@"Enter your number.");
        scanf("%i", &number);

        if(number < 0){           
            number = ABS(number);
            do {
                right_digit = number % 10;
                NSLog(@"%i", right_digit);
                number /= 10;
            } while (number != 0);

            NSLog(@"-");

        }else{
             do {
                 right_digit = number % 10;
                 NSLog(@"%i", right_digit);
                 number /= 10;
             } while (number != 0);
        }


    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's behaving as documented - a leading zero prefix to an integer constant denotes an octal number, so `0123` (in base 8) is just `83` (in base 10).

Look up the documentation of `scanf` for the full details of these conversions. Hexadecimal is also supported.  If you're writing Objective-C code, I suggest you look at the `NSString` parsing routines which have a better interface for this sort of thing.

Comment: You typed faster. :) All I'd add is that the following link is a good SO on using scanf and NSString: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3220823/using-scanf-with-nsstrings

Comment: To be clear, this will only happens with the `%i` format specifier. With `%d` the leading zeros are ignored and the decimal number is converted.